# Iwasawa-like decomposition for symplectic matrices over the integers modulo k

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, matrix-decomposition

The [Iwasawa decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition) of a real symplectic matrix $S \in \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb R)$ gives a convenient decomposition $S=KAN$ where
$$K\in \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb R) \cup \text{SO}(2n,\mathbb R)\\
A \in \mathcal{A}=\{D(\vec{\kappa}): \vec{\kappa}=(\kappa_{1},\kappa_{2}\dots,\kappa_{1}^{-1},\dots,\kappa^{-1}_{n})\}\\
N\in\mathcal{N}=\left\{\left( \begin{matrix}
A&0 \\
C&A^{-T}
\end{matrix} \right) \in \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb R): A_{ii}=1,A_{i,j<i}=0, A^{T}C=C^{T}A \right\}$$.

Does the same decomposition hold for:

- (1) symplectic matrices defined over the integers, i.e., $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb Z)$; and
- (2) for symplectic matrices defined over the integers $\mod k$, i.e., $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb Z_k)$, where $\mathbb Z_k=\{0,\dots,k-1\}$?

If not, is there some similar decomposition with the same or similar properties?